# How to use SSIS Excel Destination to populate a spreadsheet stored in TFS?

Tags: excel, ssis

In Excel, I have connected to my Team Foundation Server (TFS) Team Project by selecting the following options.

```
Team -> New List -> Connect -> Input List
```

Now, I have an empty table that I could start typing work items into but I'd like to use SSIS Excel Destination task to fill this spreadsheet with work items I am migrating from another system.

When I get to the drop down to select the spreadsheet/table the table defined in the spreadsheet (for example:`VSTS_9d9899c3_7126_458b_9c61_91ad928b8418`) is not in the list.  All the validation lists appear to be there but not the main table.

How can I use SSIS to fill a Excel spreadsheet that is connected to TFS?

Comment: Generally TFS, VSS and others have a location on a drive where you can find all the documents and stuff. If you can figure out that path, you can set that path in the connection manager of the Excel sheet.